# Hacer que el hover de un botón de el navbar ocupe todo el alto con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

llevo un buen rato tratando de que al pasar el mouse por encima de un botón de navegación, el hover ocupe todo el grosor del nav pero se ve como en la imagen. Versión de bootstrap: 5
.......................................................................................................

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>.nav-item:hover{background-color: green;}</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center ms-2" href="#">
      <div class="d-inline-flex ms-2 me-2">
        <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <h6 class="d-flex ms-2 mt-2 align-items-center text-uppercase">Facundo Duran</h6> 
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end me-2" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-3">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active text-dark" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#Experiencia">Experiencia</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#Educacion">Educación</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#Proyectos">Proyectos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image: Hover]

Comment: tenes el codigo css? el hover se muestra sobre el tamaño de la caja a la que pertenece, no ocupa el el alto del nav porque la caja no ocupa todo el grosor.

Comment: No hay nada de css, son clases de bootstrap. Lo único que añadí es la propiedad de background-color al nav-item:hover

Comment: No olvides especificar la versión de bootstrap que estás utilizando. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. De hecho, puedes crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma, moviendo tu código a un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) e incorporar el link del CSS de Bootstrap (haciendo clic en _añadir librería externa_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No uso Bootstrap pero podrias modificar los css del navbar para conseguirlo, algo como esto.

```css
.navbar {
    padding-top: 0rem!important;
    padding-bottom: 0rem!important;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0rem;
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
}
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: 20px 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>.nav-item:hover{background-color: green;}</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center ms-2" href="#">
      <div class="d-inline-flex ms-2 me-2">
        <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <h6 class="d-flex ms-2 mt-2 align-items-center text-uppercase">Facundo Duran</h6> 
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end me-2" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-3">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active text-dark" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#Experiencia">Experiencia</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#Educacion">Educación</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#Proyectos">Proyectos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Básicamente lo que estoy haciendo el eliminar el padding top y bottom. Como estoy sobreescribiendo instrucciones anteriores uso !important, generalmente no se recomienda usarlo a menos que sea necesario, si le das mas clases puedes ser mas especifico para que la regla tenga mayor relevancia y así evitar usar !important.